# Chrome err_connection_reset on lte connection

Tags: django, apache, google-chrome, certbot, ovh

So I have a very weird problem, I have a website and when I'm connected through wifi everything is fine, chrome and Mozilla are loading my website.
But when I switch to LTE internet my website is working fine only on Mozilla. **Chrome is throwing ERR_CONNECTION_RESET error**. I tried turning off firewall and restarting the server, but it doesn't change anything. The website was made in Django.

On the other hand, when I'm connecting directly to IP, it's working (I see 404 from apache, but that's because it's configurated to work with domain).
I'm using also certbot, but it's not looking like certbot fault. It's rather something connected with domain configuration.

I'm using OVH services both for server and domain. In domain I added only ip4 and ip6, DNS servers were left in the default configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so to fix it I removed IPv6 redirect from the domain. And now it's working. I hope that it will help someone :)